# Associating class_names with Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

When using [`image_dataset_from_directory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) I have noticed the output `BatchDataset` has a `class_names` attribute that is a `list` of labels.  This is nice.

I have a tensorflow `MapDataset` that I have hand-created via `Dataset.from_tensor_slices` + `Dataset.map`.  I can manually set the `class_names` attribute into that `MapDataset`, but when I call `my_dataset.batch(32)` the `class_names` attribute is not carried over to the new `BatchDataset`.

How can I add `class_names` to a hand-created `Dataset`?  I see [`tf.features.ClassLabel`](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/features/ClassLabel), but I can't figure out how to connect it to  a `Dataset`.

I am using `tensorflow~=2.4` with Python 3.8.

Comment: how is your data directory organized, if you use image_generator.flow_from_directory . it will automatically pick up the label from folder name

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that I can only test on tensorflow2.9, and I havn't used `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` since its high integration.
Do you mean the lables that `class_a`, `class_b`, etc. in [the image_dataset_from_directory's sample](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) ?

If so, in tf2.9, you can use attr `element_spec` to check, which will be determined by `from_tensor_slices` and maintained for ever in next procedures.

Additionally, attr `class_names` can be set arbitrarily since it is not internally maintained by `tf.data.dataset`.

I have checked the source codes in tf2.4.0 and find it had implemented attr `element_spec` already. So I think you can use it.

Here is sample code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = {
    "class_a": [tf.constant(v) for v in range(10)],
    "class_b": [tf.constant(v) for v in range(10,20)]
}
a = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dataset)
print(a.element_spec)
# {'class_a': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), 'class_b': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)}

a.class_names = "alielie"
print(a.class_names,a.element_spec)
# alielie {'class_a': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), 'class_b': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)}

a = a.map(lambda x:x)
a.class_names = "alielie1"
print(a.class_names,a.element_spec)
# alielie1 {'class_a': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), 'class_b': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)}

a = a.batch(5)
a.class_names = "alielie2"
print(a.class_names,a.element_spec)
# alielie2 {'class_a': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), 'class_b': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)}
```

And the following is my test for image_dataset_from_directory's `class_names`, where `class_names` just works when building the dataset, and dynamic modification is not supported originally. More precisely, dynamic modification on `class_names` is not forbidden but does not work as we expected.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib
dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

batch_size = 1
img_height = 180
img_width = 180

#1 the labele will be [0]
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  labels='inferred',
  class_names = ['daisy','dandelion', 'sunflowers', 'tulips','roses'],
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  shuffle=False,
  seed=None,
  batch_size=batch_size)
for item in train_ds.take(5):
    print(tf.reduce_mean(item[0]),item[1])

#2 the labele will be [1]
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  labels='inferred',
  class_names = ['dandelion','daisy','sunflowers', 'tulips','roses'],
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  shuffle=False,
  seed=None,
  batch_size=batch_size)
for item in train_ds.take(5):
    print(tf.reduce_mean(item[0]),item[1])

#3 the labele will still be [0],  dynamic modification does not work
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  labels='inferred',
  class_names = ['daisy','dandelion','sunflowers','tulips','roses'],
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  shuffle=False,
  seed=None,
  batch_size=batch_size)
train_ds.class_names = ['dandelion','daisy','sunflowers', 'tulips','roses']
for item in train_ds.take(5):
    print(tf.reduce_mean(item[0]),item[1])
```

So, if you just want to show such like `class_names` in  `Dataset.from_tensor_slices`, `element_spec` is the supported attr, as long as giving `Dataset.from_tensor_slices` the data in `Typing` `dict[str,list[tf.Tensor]]`.  This attr will not be cut off
by calling `.batch` or `.map`.

If you want to modify `class_names` dinamicly, unfortunately，
dynamic modification does not work in `image_dataset_from_directory`. Meanwhile, `Dataset.from_tensor_slices` does not support this feature too.

Comment: So you're saying just manually set `class_names` into the dataset?  By the way, I discovered the issue [Mapping a dataset squashes class_names from image_dataset_from_directory](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/56233), which means if you set `class_names` _before_ calling `.batch` or `.map` it will be clobbered

Comment: I have made additional tests. Do you mean modify `class_names` dynamiclly?